# Media image cron upload is failing to upload any images to my simple products

Tags: product-attribute, collection, import, importexport, ee-1.13

Front image should only load for configs and this works fine. Simples should load front and back and all other angles. It looks for F (front) and B (back), sets those to 1 or 2, everything else is just added at the end in the order it's imported. Something broke and now nothing is being imported to simples, well actually sometimes a _F will be upload to simples but it's not importing anything else. I think the `_getPosition` function is the issue.

Here is the error and file naming convention:

```
Skipping image d65116r4_blk_1.jpg, no products matched.
Skipping image d65116r4_blk_2.jpg, no products matched.
Skipping image d65116r4_blk_3.jpg, no products matched.
Skipping image d65116r4_blk_b.jpg, no products matched.
Skipping image d65116r4_blk_f.jpg, no products matched. (This will upload for configs and most of the time simples but none of the other four above load for simples)
```

Please see my code below:

Model/Adapter/Product/Media.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Most of the following code was taken from Mage Core, and modified slightly for our needs.
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage()
 */
class OnePica_FullCircle_Model_Adapter_Product_Media
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{
    /**
     * Add media file to products
     */
    public function saveRow(array $importData)
    {
        if (empty($importData['path'])) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, required field "%s" is not defined.', 'path');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        if (empty($importData['file'])) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping import row, required field "%s" is not defined.', 'file');
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        $path = $importData['path'];
        $file = $importData['file'];

        // If store hasn't been set, set to default
        if ($this->_store === null) {
            $this->_store = $this->getStoreById(1);
        }

        //Load list of products to add to
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection($file);

        //Add image to the media directory
        $savedFileName = $this->_addMediaFile($path . DS . $file);

        // get image import cache setting
        $imageImportCache = Mage::getSingleton('myfoldername_fullcircle/image_import_cache')->load(1);

        //Add image to products
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $product->setStoreId($this->_store->getId());

            //Load Product Images
            $product->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')
                ->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);

            //Check to see if we already have the image in the gallery
            $found = false;
            $curImages = $product->getMediaGallery();
            if (isset($curImages['images']) && is_array($curImages['images']) && count($curImages)) {
                foreach ($curImages['images'] as $curImage) {
                    if ($curImage['file'] == $savedFileName) {
                        //A similar image already exists..mark that the cache needs to be cleared
                        $found = true;
                        // set to clear cache
                        $imageImportCache->setIsClear(true)
                            ->setUpdatedAt(now())
                            ->save();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Add Image to Product
            if (!$found) {
                //This event gets run in the core, so let's also run it
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_media_add_image', array('product' => $product, 'image' => $path . DS . $file));
                //Add image to product gallery
                $this->_addImageToProduct($product, $savedFileName);
            } else {
                // Even if the image is found, we still want to set the product attributes
                $this->_setProductMediaAttributes($product, $savedFileName);
                $product->save();
            }

            // Disable EU Images in US and EU images in US
            $europeanImageIds = array();
            $usImageIds = array();
            if (is_array($curImages) && isset($curImages['images']) && is_array($curImages['images'])) {
                foreach ($curImages['images'] as $img) {
                    if (stripos(basename($img['file']), '51_') === 0 && array_key_exists('value_id', $img)) {
                        $europeanImageIds[] = $img['value_id'];
                    } else if (stripos(basename($img['file']), '51_') === false && array_key_exists('value_id', $img)) {
                        $usImageIds[] = $img['value_id'];
                    }
                }

                $helper = Mage::helper('myfoldername_eudataflow');

                $usStoreIds = $helper->getStoreIdsByCompanyNumber('01');
                $euStoreIds = $helper->getStoreIdsByCompanyNumber('51');

                $adapter = Mage::getModel('myfoldername_eudataflow/convert_adapter_product');
                $adapter->disableImages($europeanImageIds, $usStoreIds);
                $adapter->disableImages($usImageIds, $euStoreIds);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get configured store id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getStoreId()
    {
        if (null === $this->getBatchParams('store')) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (int)$this->getBatchParams('store');
    }

    /**
     * Get collection of products matching the media file
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection($file)
    {
        //Initialize collection
        $collection = $this->getProductModel()->reset()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId());

        //Load source for electric_color
        $colorSource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
            ->getAttribute('color')
            ->getSource();

        //Parse filename for product details
        $parts = $this->_parseFileName($file);
        if (count(explode('_', $file)) != $parts['valid_parts']) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping image %s, invalid filename format.',$file);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }
        //Filter by style
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('style_number', $parts['sku']);

        //Filter by color
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', $colorSource->getOptionId($parts['color']));
        if (strtolower($parts['angle']) == 'f' || strtolower($parts['angle']) == 'frt') {
            //Front angle...add to configurable as well
            $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`e`.`sku` = ?', $parts['sku']);

            // Front + color - see if there's a split configurable to add it to as well
            $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`e`.`sku` = ?', $parts['sku'] . $parts['color']);
        }

        //Set a safety guard of 100 products just to make sure
        if ($collection->getSize() > 100) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping image %s, too many products matched.',$file);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }

        //Throw an exception if there aren't any products
        if (!$collection->getSize()) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping image %s, no products matched.',$file);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Take the filename and get sku, color, angle
     * 
     * @param $file
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _parseFileName($file)
    {
        $parts = explode('_', $file);
        return array(
            'sku' => $parts[0],
            'color' => $parts[1],
            'angle_extension' => $parts[2],
            'angle' => substr($parts[2], 0, 1),
            'valid_parts' => 3,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Manually add image to media directory
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _addMediaFile($file)
    {
        $pathinfo       = pathinfo($file);
//         $fileName       = strtolower($pathinfo['basename']); //Force all images to lowercase
        $fileName = $pathinfo['basename'];
        $fileName       = Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getCorrectFileName($fileName);
        $dispretionPath = Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getDispretionPath($fileName);
        $fileName       = str_replace(DS, '/', $dispretionPath . DS . $fileName);

        //Make sure image exists in media folder, add it if it doesn't
        $mediaConfig = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config');
        $mediaPath = $mediaConfig->getMediaPath($fileName);

        $ioAdapter = new Varien_Io_File();
        $ioAdapter->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $distanationDirectory = dirname($mediaPath);
        try {
            $ioAdapter->open(array('path' => $distanationDirectory));

            /** @var $storageHelper Mage_Core_Helper_File_Storage_Database */
            $storageHelper = Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database');
            $ioAdapter->mv($file, $mediaPath);
            $storageHelper->saveFile($mediaConfig->getMediaShortUrl($fileName));
            $ioAdapter->chmod($mediaPath, 0777);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skipping image %s, failed to move file.',$file);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }

        return $fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Add image to the product
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addImageToProduct($product, $fileName)
    {
        //Get next position value
        $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
        if (!is_array($mediaGalleryData)) {
            $mediaGalleryData = array(
                'images' => array()
            );
        }
        $position = $this->_getPosition($product, $mediaGalleryData, $fileName);

        //Add image to gallery data
        $mediaGallery = $this->getAttribute('media_gallery');
        $mediaResource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_backend_media');
        $valueId = $mediaResource->insertGallery(array(
            'entity_id' => $product->getId(),
            'attribute_id' => $mediaGallery->getAttributeId(),
            'value' => $fileName,
        ));
        $mediaGalleryData['images'][] = array(
            'value_id' => $valueId,
            'file'     => $fileName,
            'position' => $position,
            'label'    => '',
            'disabled' => 0,
        );

        // Set product attributes
        $this->_setProductMediaAttributes($product, $fileName);

        // Update the media gallery data
        $product->setData('media_gallery', $mediaGalleryData);

        //Save product
        Mage::helper('onepica_fullcircle')->fixUrlKey($product);
        $product->save();

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the position for the media image
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param array $mediaGalleryData
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getPosition($product, $mediaGalleryData, $fileName)
    {
        $position = 0;

        $isFrontImage = preg_match('/_f\./', strtolower($fileName)) || preg_match('/_frt\./', strtolower($fileName));
        $isBackImage  = preg_match('/_b\./', strtolower($fileName)) || preg_match('/_bck\./', strtolower($fileName));

        if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
            //Check for a front angle
            if ($isFrontImage) {
                return 1;
            }
            //Check for a back angle
            if ($isBackImage) {
                return 2;
            }
            //Make sure new position is at least 10
            $position = 9;
        }

        // Split configurables - if the image is a front angle for that color,
        // set it to default.
        if ($product->getTypeId() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
            $styleNumber = $product->getStyleNumber();
            $sku = $product->getSku();

            $imageContainsColor = false;
            $color = str_replace($styleNumber, '', $sku);
            if (!empty($color)) {
                $imageContainsColor = false !== stristr($fileName, $color);
            }

            if ($imageContainsColor && $isFrontImage) {
                return 1;
            }

            if ($imageContainsColor && $isBackImage) {
                return 2;
            }
        }        

        //Get position of last media image
        $lastImage = end($mediaGalleryData['images']);
        reset($mediaGalleryData);
        if ($lastImage) {
            $position = max((int)$lastImage['position'], $position);
        }
        return $position + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Set image, small_image, thumbnail for product
     * 
     * @param $product
     * @param $fileName
     */
    protected function _setProductMediaAttributes($product, $fileName)
    {
        $firstPosition = false;
        $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
        $position = $this->_getPosition($product, $mediaGalleryData, $fileName);
        if (is_array($mediaGalleryData)) {
            $firstImage = @current($mediaGalleryData['images']);
            $firstPosition = (int)@$firstImage['position']; // Could be zero
        }

        //Set Product Attributes
        // No images yet, lesser position, or is front image - set it as default
        if (false === $firstPosition || $position < $firstPosition || $position === 1) {
            foreach (array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail') as $mediaAttributeCode) {
                $product->setData($mediaAttributeCode, $fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process after import data
     */
    public function finish()
    {
        // override parent, do not reindex
    }
}
```

I really look forward to some help. Thank you.